# Rav Ovadia Yosef's Sefer Chazon Ovadia

Tags: hacham-ovadia-yosef

Does anybody know how I can access חזון עובדיה (ארבע תעניות), עמוד תמא-תמג  which deals with the Kotel Ha'Maaravi (the Western Wall).

Unfortunately the sefer is not in my shul's Beit Medrash.

Thank you

Comment: A first step would be quoting the last explicit source whatever seffer you are quoting from referenced Chazzon Ovadia. That would at least help anyone understand which chelek שם is.

Comment: @user6591 based on other works that reference it, I've sleuthed that he's looking for the volume on תעניות.

Comment: try a sefardi shul, if you have one nearby.

Comment: https://judaicaspot.com/products/%D7%97%D7%96%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%91%D7%93%D7%99%D7%94-%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A2-%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9D

Comment: Thank you everyone.  I had seen the reference only in secondary source, so i did not have either an accurate quote or better citation for my question, but I am glad for what was provided, which was exactly on point

Comment: The Rambam Library, in Tel Aviv, has a free online service, scanning services and delivery of old and new books and periodicals free of charge.
They try to answer every request within 24 hours.
rambaml1@gmail.com

Answer (score 4):

It goes on for another 30 or so pages for the rest of the chapter [image][image][image][image]